# What is difference between .apply() method and .copyWith() method in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, google-fonts

what is the difference between these methods and when is best time to use one of them?

- apply method

```
// I use GoogleFonts package
textTheme: GoogleFonts.pangolinTextTheme(textTheme).apply(
  bodyColor: Colors.red,
  displayColor: Colors.red,
),
```

- copyWith method

```
textTheme: GoogleFonts.pangolinTextTheme(textTheme).copyWith(
  titleLarge: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)
),
```

I need to know what is difreans just that to use in my apps

Answer (score 0):

They are very similar. They both are used to get a copy of a `TextStyle` in which you make some changes. But they have some different parameters. Most notable, `apply` has several factor and delta parameters that scales certain values based on their original value. You can easily investigate yourself what the exact differences are by looking at their implementation. In Android Studio you can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click the method to see it. If you are unable to, check out their implementations below.

apply:

```
  /// Creates a copy of this text style replacing or altering the specified
  /// properties.
  ///
  /// The non-numeric properties [color], [fontFamily], [decoration],
  /// [decorationColor] and [decorationStyle] are replaced with the new values.
  ///
  /// [foreground] will be given preference over [color] if it is not null and
  /// [background] will be given preference over [backgroundColor] if it is not
  /// null.
  ///
  /// The numeric properties are multiplied by the given factors and then
  /// incremented by the given deltas.
  ///
  /// For example, `style.apply(fontSizeFactor: 2.0, fontSizeDelta: 1.0)` would
  /// return a [TextStyle] whose [fontSize] is `style.fontSize * 2.0 + 1.0`.
  ///
  /// For the [fontWeight], the delta is applied to the [FontWeight] enum index
  /// values, so that for instance `style.apply(fontWeightDelta: -2)` when
  /// applied to a `style` whose [fontWeight] is [FontWeight.w500] will return a
  /// [TextStyle] with a [FontWeight.w300].
  ///
  /// The numeric arguments must not be null.
  ///
  /// If the underlying values are null, then the corresponding factors and/or
  /// deltas must not be specified.
  ///
  /// If [foreground] is specified on this object, then applying [color] here
  /// will have no effect and if [background] is specified on this object, then
  /// applying [backgroundColor] here will have no effect either.
  TextStyle apply({
    Color? color,
    Color? backgroundColor,
    TextDecoration? decoration,
    Color? decorationColor,
    TextDecorationStyle? decorationStyle,
    double decorationThicknessFactor = 1.0,
    double decorationThicknessDelta = 0.0,
    String? fontFamily,
    List<String>? fontFamilyFallback,
    double fontSizeFactor = 1.0,
    double fontSizeDelta = 0.0,
    int fontWeightDelta = 0,
    FontStyle? fontStyle,
    double letterSpacingFactor = 1.0,
    double letterSpacingDelta = 0.0,
    double wordSpacingFactor = 1.0,
    double wordSpacingDelta = 0.0,
    double heightFactor = 1.0,
    double heightDelta = 0.0,
    TextBaseline? textBaseline,
    ui.TextLeadingDistribution? leadingDistribution,
    Locale? locale,
    List<ui.Shadow>? shadows,
    List<ui.FontFeature>? fontFeatures,
    List<ui.FontVariation>? fontVariations,
    String? package,
    TextOverflow? overflow,
  }) {
    assert(fontSizeFactor != null);
    assert(fontSizeDelta != null);
    assert(fontSize != null || (fontSizeFactor == 1.0 && fontSizeDelta == 0.0));
    assert(fontWeightDelta != null);
    assert(fontWeight != null || fontWeightDelta == 0.0);
    assert(letterSpacingFactor != null);
    assert(letterSpacingDelta != null);
    assert(letterSpacing != null || (letterSpacingFactor == 1.0 && letterSpacingDelta == 0.0));
    assert(wordSpacingFactor != null);
    assert(wordSpacingDelta != null);
    assert(wordSpacing != null || (wordSpacingFactor == 1.0 && wordSpacingDelta == 0.0));
    assert(heightFactor != null);
    assert(heightDelta != null);
    assert(decorationThicknessFactor != null);
    assert(decorationThicknessDelta != null);
    assert(decorationThickness != null || (decorationThicknessFactor == 1.0 && decorationThicknessDelta == 0.0));

    String? modifiedDebugLabel;
    assert(() {
      if (debugLabel != null) {
        modifiedDebugLabel = '($debugLabel).apply';
      }
      return true;
    }());

    return TextStyle(
      inherit: inherit,
      color: foreground == null ? color ?? this.color : null,
      backgroundColor: background == null ? backgroundColor ?? this.backgroundColor : null,
      fontFamily: fontFamily ?? _fontFamily,
      fontFamilyFallback: fontFamilyFallback ?? this.fontFamilyFallback,
      fontSize: fontSize == null ? null : fontSize! * fontSizeFactor + fontSizeDelta,
      fontWeight: fontWeight == null ? null : FontWeight.values[(fontWeight!.index + fontWeightDelta).clamp(0, FontWeight.values.length - 1)], // ignore_clamp_double_lint
      fontStyle: fontStyle ?? this.fontStyle,
      letterSpacing: letterSpacing == null ? null : letterSpacing! * letterSpacingFactor + letterSpacingDelta,
      wordSpacing: wordSpacing == null ? null : wordSpacing! * wordSpacingFactor + wordSpacingDelta,
      textBaseline: textBaseline ?? this.textBaseline,
      height: height == null ? null : height! * heightFactor + heightDelta,
      leadingDistribution: leadingDistribution ?? this.leadingDistribution,
      locale: locale ?? this.locale,
      foreground: foreground,
      background: background,
      shadows: shadows ?? this.shadows,
      fontFeatures: fontFeatures ?? this.fontFeatures,
      fontVariations: fontVariations ?? this.fontVariations,
      decoration: decoration ?? this.decoration,
      decorationColor: decorationColor ?? this.decorationColor,
      decorationStyle: decorationStyle ?? this.decorationStyle,
      decorationThickness: decorationThickness == null ? null : decorationThickness! * decorationThicknessFactor + decorationThicknessDelta,
      overflow: overflow ?? this.overflow,
      package: package ?? _package,
      debugLabel: modifiedDebugLabel,
    );
  }
```

`copyWith`:

```
  /// Creates a copy of this text style but with the given fields replaced with
  /// the new values.
  ///
  /// One of [color] or [foreground] must be null, and if this has [foreground]
  /// specified it will be given preference over any color parameter.
  ///
  /// One of [backgroundColor] or [background] must be null, and if this has
  /// [background] specified it will be given preference over any
  /// backgroundColor parameter.
  TextStyle copyWith({
    bool? inherit,
    Color? color,
    Color? backgroundColor,
    double? fontSize,
    FontWeight? fontWeight,
    FontStyle? fontStyle,
    double? letterSpacing,
    double? wordSpacing,
    TextBaseline? textBaseline,
    double? height,
    ui.TextLeadingDistribution? leadingDistribution,
    Locale? locale,
    Paint? foreground,
    Paint? background,
    List<ui.Shadow>? shadows,
    List<ui.FontFeature>? fontFeatures,
    List<ui.FontVariation>? fontVariations,
    TextDecoration? decoration,
    Color? decorationColor,
    TextDecorationStyle? decorationStyle,
    double? decorationThickness,
    String? debugLabel,
    String? fontFamily,
    List<String>? fontFamilyFallback,
    String? package,
    TextOverflow? overflow,
  }) {
    assert(color == null || foreground == null, _kColorForegroundWarning);
    assert(backgroundColor == null || background == null, _kColorBackgroundWarning);
    String? newDebugLabel;
    assert(() {
      if (this.debugLabel != null) {
        newDebugLabel = debugLabel ?? '(${this.debugLabel}).copyWith';
      }
      return true;
    }());

    return TextStyle(
      inherit: inherit ?? this.inherit,
      color: this.foreground == null && foreground == null ? color ?? this.color : null,
      backgroundColor: this.background == null && background == null ? backgroundColor ?? this.backgroundColor : null,
      fontSize: fontSize ?? this.fontSize,
      fontWeight: fontWeight ?? this.fontWeight,
      fontStyle: fontStyle ?? this.fontStyle,
      letterSpacing: letterSpacing ?? this.letterSpacing,
      wordSpacing: wordSpacing ?? this.wordSpacing,
      textBaseline: textBaseline ?? this.textBaseline,
      height: height ?? this.height,
      leadingDistribution: leadingDistribution ?? this.leadingDistribution,
      locale: locale ?? this.locale,
      foreground: foreground ?? this.foreground,
      background: background ?? this.background,
      shadows: shadows ?? this.shadows,
      fontFeatures: fontFeatures ?? this.fontFeatures,
      fontVariations: fontVariations ?? this.fontVariations,
      decoration: decoration ?? this.decoration,
      decorationColor: decorationColor ?? this.decorationColor,
      decorationStyle: decorationStyle ?? this.decorationStyle,
      decorationThickness: decorationThickness ?? this.decorationThickness,
      debugLabel: newDebugLabel,
      fontFamily: fontFamily ?? _fontFamily,
      fontFamilyFallback: fontFamilyFallback ?? this.fontFamilyFallback,
      package: package ?? _package,
      overflow: overflow ?? this.overflow,
    );
  }
```